# How to redirect from one html file uploaded to a localhost to a different html file on disk using PHP?

Tags: php, html, c++, apache, xampp

I currently have this pretty basic HTML form.

```
<form method="post" action="send.php" >
    <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Search..." name="search" id="search" autocomplete="on" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Search" size="80" />
</form>
```

Now, I'm looking to send a parameter taken from a variable in HTML to a function written in C++.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){

        $text=$_POST['search'];

        system("PageRank_Final.exe $text");
    }
?>
```

I already have that working. I can execute my C++ program from HTML using PHP. Now, after the program is executed I want to be redirected to `a.html` file that is generated from one of my functions on C++.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){

        $text=$_POST['search'];

        system("PageRank_Final.exe $text");
        header("Location: Pagerank.html);
    }
?>
```

Adding the **header("Location: Pagerank.html);** does not redirect me to that HTML file. The file is saved on the `htdocs` folder on the `xampp` installation folder.

Am I using the `header()` function incorrectly?

Feel free to ask questions in the case that I was not clear enough.

Comment: `POST` variables, as well as `GET` variables, *must* be sanitized before passing them as argument to `system()` function... You never know what a malicious user could put inside `search` variable.

Comment: Regarding your question, try to use a full url like this: `header("Location: https://www.yoursite.com/Pagerank.html");`. Furthermore, please read the documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php and in particular read these sentences: "The system() call also tries to automatically flush the web server's output buffer after each line of output if PHP is running as a server module.

If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function."

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect to the page looks correct. I am using `header("Location:a.php");` in my code aswell, and it is working.

You might wanan check if the system() call, terminates. If not, your header won't be excecuted, as it is still in the system call.

Answer (score 0):

The `header` function only works if no output has been generated. Almost certainly your .exe file is generating some output, even if just whitespace, and keeping `header` from executing. You can turn on error reporting by pasting this right after your opening php tag to verify:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```